# Market Portfolio Binary Search Tree

Tags: c++, time-limit-exceeded, vectors, binary-search-tree

I'm trying to solve the following problem here:

> First line of input contains the number of days D. The next d lines contains a character c and a number x. If c is B, then buy stock . If c is S, then sell stock x if it is present. If c is R, then ask if the stock x was present in his portfolio. For each of the days of type R x, print "YES" (without the quotes) if the stock x is present in the portfolio else print "NO" (without the quotes).

The criteria for implementing the above question is to just use the following three ```cpp`` libraries:

1. iostream,
2. cstdlib,
3. vector

Thus my question to optimise the time using the binary search tree.
My code for the same is:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main() {
    int D;
    std::cin >> D;

    std::vector<int> portfolio;

    while (D--) {
        char c;
        int x;
        std::cin >> c >> x;

        if (c == 'B') {
            // Buy stock
            portfolio.push_back(x);
        } else if (c == 'S') {
            // Sell stock if it is present
            for (int i = 0; i < portfolio.size(); ++i) {
                if (portfolio[i] == x) {
                    portfolio.erase(portfolio.begin() + i);
                    break;  // Found and sold the stock, so break the loop
                }
            }
        } else if (c == 'R') {
            // Check if the stock is present in the portfolio
            bool found = false;
            for (int i = 0; i < portfolio.size(); ++i) {
                if (portfolio[i] == x) {
                    found = true;
                    break;  // Found the stock, so break the loop
                }
            }
            if (found) {
                std::cout << "YES" << std::endl;
            } else {
                std::cout << "NO" << std::endl;
            }
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I'm maintaining the portfolio here using a vector, but the issue I feel is time complexity will be affected at the stage when we search for the stock in the portfolio. If it is added at the end, the loop will traverse all the way when this can be optimized if we just maintain a binary search tree. I was hoping to get a BST implementation of the same.

To add, the exact language of the question is:

> For each of the d days, Avi meets one person among Bansal, Shrey, or Radha. If he meets Bansal on ith day, he advises him to buy the stock s; and if Avi doesn't already have that stock in his portfolio then he buys it. If he meets Shrey on ith day, he advises him to sell the stock si and if he has that stock in his portfolio, he sells that stock. If he meets Radha on ith day she asks him to check if the stock s; is present in his portfolio.

> Help Avi maintain his stock portfolio and answer all the queries asked by Radha.

> Input Format

> First line of input contains the number of days D.

> The next d lines contains a character c and a number x.

> If c is B, then Avi met Bansal and got advice to buy stock x.

> If c is S, then Avi met Shrey and got advice to sell stock x.

> If c is R, then Avi met Radha and was asked if the stock x was present in his portfolio.

> Constraints

> 1<=d <= 2*10^5

> C=B|S|R

> 1<=x<=10^9

> Output Format

> For each of the days of type R x, print "YES" (without the quotes) if the stock x is present in the portfolio else print "NO" (without the quotes).

Comment: If you want a BST: [`std::set`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set). But even better is a hash table: [`std::unordered_set`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_set). But if you know the maximum value of `x`, the best might be [`std::vector<bool>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector_bool), where each bit signifies if stock is present, with `x` being the index. C++ comes with lots of useful [containers](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container).

Comment: @G.Sliepen I've made edits to the question with the exact criteria to be followed. We can just use vector to implement BST.

Comment: If you already know you should implement a BST, then you should do that. We don't write code for you at Code Review, we only review what you have already written.

Comment: @G.Sliepen it is just a suggestion to use BST on my part, and we can implement some other data structure too if it can improve the code

Comment: Sure, but if you know the code is not working as fast as necessary, and you already know a way to speed it up, why don't you implement the better solution first and then ask for a review of that?

Comment: Can you provide test data to show that the code is working as intended? We can't write code for you, we can only make observations about the code. We will not write a BST solution for you. You might want to look at `vector.find()` as a code improvement.

Comment: @pacmaninbw yes, i'm actually working on the code currently. will update as and when i get any

Answer (score -2, accepted):

````
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

struct TreeNode {
    int val;
    TreeNode *left;
    TreeNode *right;
    TreeNode() : val(0), left(nullptr), right(nullptr) {}
    TreeNode(int x) : val(x), left(nullptr), right(nullptr) {}
    TreeNode(int x, TreeNode *left, TreeNode *right) : val(x), left(left), right(right) {}
};

TreeNode* insertIntoBST(TreeNode* root, int val) {
    if(root == NULL)
        return new TreeNode(val);
        
    TreeNode *curr = root;
    while(true){
        if(val < curr->val){
            if(curr->left != NULL)
                curr = curr->left;
            else{
                curr->left = new TreeNode(val);
                break;
            }
        }
        else{
            if(curr->right != NULL)
                curr = curr->right;
            else{
                curr->right = new TreeNode(val);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return root;
}

bool searchBST(TreeNode* root, int val) {
    if(root == NULL)
        return false;
        
    if(root->val == val)
        return true;
    else if(val < root->val)
        return searchBST(root->left, val);
    else
        return searchBST(root->right, val);
        
    return false;
}

TreeNode* deleteNode(TreeNode* root, int key) {
    if(root != NULL){
        
        if(key < root->val) 
            root->left = deleteNode(root->left, key);
         
        else if(key > root->val) 
            root->right = deleteNode(root->right, key);  
             
        else{
            
            if(root->left == NULL && root->right == NULL) 
                return NULL; 
            
            if (root->left == NULL || root->right == NULL)
                return root->left ? root->left : root->right; 
            
            TreeNode* temp = root->left;
            while(temp->right != NULL) 
                temp = temp->right; 
            root->val = temp->val;     
            root->left = deleteNode(root->left, temp->val); 
        }
    }
    return root;
}

int main() {
    int D;
    std::cin >> D;

    TreeNode* portfolio = nullptr;

    while (D--) {
        char c;
        int x;
        std::cin >> c >> x;

        if (c == 'B') {
            // Buy stock
            portfolio=insertIntoBST(portfolio, x);
        } else if (c == 'S') {
            portfolio=deleteNode(portfolio, x);
        } else if (c == 'R') {
            // Check if the stock is present in the portfolio
            bool found = searchBST(portfolio,x);
            if (found) {
                std::cout << "YES" << std::endl;
            } else {
                std::cout << "NO" << std::endl;
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```
````

Comment: If you want this code reviewed, you should just update your question with it. This is fine since there is no other answer yet.

Comment: This is the answer with the BST Implementation. I can't give a green tick to my answer before 24 hours thus the confusion

Comment: But this answer isn't a review of the code in your question. This site is about *[reviewing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_review)* code, not solving code challenges.

Comment: Someone in the question suggested I implement it myself, as I thought I knew how to make the code faster. Now that I did I thought I need to post it

Comment: Yes, but post your BST solution as a question, not as an answer. If it's a question, we can review it. As an answer, it fails to meet [our requirements](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Welcome to the Code Review Community. While this might be a good answer on stackoverflow, it is not a good answer on Code Review. A good answer on Code Review contains at least one insightful observation about the code. Alternate code only solutions are considered poor answers and may be down voted or deleted by the community. Please read [How do I write a good answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer).